# SQL selection of last period

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table like this:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr><td>ID</td><td>status</td><td>start_date</td><td>end_date</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>A</td><td>2015-01-01</td><td>2015-12-31</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>B</td><td>2016-01-01</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>C</td><td>NULL</td><td>2016-12-31</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>D</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
</table>
```

I must do a trigger in MySQL to update a main table with the last status of a subject.

To do this I must select for every `ID` the last `status` based on the period between `start_date` and `end_date` that can be NULL if didn't known.

I write this SQL statement test:

```
SELECT *
FROM My_Table AS T
WHERE T.start_date Is Null AND
T.end_date In(SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID)
OR
T.start_date In(SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID) AND 
T.end_date Is Null
OR
T.start_date In(SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID) AND
T.end_date In(SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID
);
```

Is there a shorten method to do this?

In practice I want a WHERE clause that catch each of these cases (a = start_date, b=end_date):

`a = MAX AND b = MAX OR
a = NULL AND b = MAX OR
a = MAX AND b = NULL OR
a = NULL AND b = NULL`

Comment: I'd skip the triggers, and instead have a view.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly simplified query which returns exactly the same result set as the query in your question. It uses only two subqueries instead of four (no duplicated subqueries):

```
SELECT *
FROM My_Table AS T
WHERE 
  (T.start_date Is Null OR T.start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID)) AND
  (T.end_date Is Null OR T.end_date = (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID)) AND 
  (T.start_date Is NOT Null OR T.end_date Is NOT Null)
;
```

Note that it does NOT include the `a = NULL AND b = NULL` case. To include it as well, the last AND-clause must be removed, i.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM My_Table AS T
WHERE 
  (T.start_date Is Null OR T.start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID)) AND 
  (T.end_date Is Null OR T.end_date = (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM My_Table WHERE ID = T.ID)) 
;
```